# How do i send the data from one page to the other using history.push

Tags: reactjs

I have tried pushing the data to another page using history.push however I am unable to send the data

the code is

```
class DisplayMasterfile extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getData();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div id="outerDiv">
                    {this.props.masterfile.map(masterfile => (
                        <div className="Masterfile">
                            <table>
                                <thead>
                                    <th> CODE</th>
                                    <th> HEAD OF ACCOUNT</th>
                                    <th> ADDRESS</th>
                                    <th> TELEPHONE NO</th>
                                    <th> SALES_TAX</th>
                                    <th> OPENING_BALANCE</th>
                                    <th> AREA</th>

                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <td> {masterfile.code}</td>
                                    <td> {masterfile.head_of_account}</td>
                                    <td> {masterfile.address}</td>
                                    <td> {masterfile.telephone_no}</td>
                                    <td> {masterfile.sales_tax}</td>
                                    <td> {masterfile.opening_balance}</td>
                                    <td> {masterfile.area}</td>
 <button onClick={() => {
                                        this.props.history.push("/masterfileupdate/" + masterfile.masterfile_no,
                                            {
                                                masterfile
                                            });
                                    }}
                                        id="editBtn">Edit</button>
                                    <button id="delButton" onClick={() => this.props.deleteData(masterfile.masterfile_no)}>Delete</button>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>

                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    masterfile: state.masterfileReducer.masterfile,
    error: state.masterfileReducer.error
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    { getData, deleteData, updateData }
)(DisplayMasterfile)
```

and in the update page I have been calling all the values but still I am not being able to receive the data onto the other page

```
class UpdateMasterfile extends Component {
    state = {
        masterfile_no: this.props.match.params.masterfilemasterfile_no,
        code: this.props.location.state.masterfile.code,
        head_of_account: this.props.location.state.masterfile.head_of_account,
        address: this.props.location.state.masterfile.address,
        telephone_no: this.props.location.state.masterfile.telephone_no,
        sales_tax: this.props.location.state.masterfile.sales_tax,
        opening_balance: this.props.location.state.masterfile.opening_balance,
        area: this.props.location.state.masterfile.area
    }
    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.getData();
    }
    onChange = e => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.targer.value })
    };
    render() {
        console.log(this.props);
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="masterfile-update">
                    <h1>Update Data</h1>
                    <p>
                        <label className="masterfile-add">
                            CODE
                    <input type="text"
                                name="code"
                                onChange={this.onChange}
                                value={this.state.code} />
                        </label>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label className="masterfile-add">
                            Head OF ACCOUNT
                    <input type="text"
                                name="head_of_account"
                                onChange={this.onChange}
                                value={this.state.head_of_account} />
                        </label>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label className="masterfile-add">
                            ADDRESS
                    <input type="text"
                                name="address"
                                onChange={this.onChange}
                                value={this.state.address} />
                        </label>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label className="masterfile-add">
                            TELEPHONE NO
                    <input type="text"
                                name="telephone_no"
                                onChange={this.onChange}
                                value={this.state.telephone_no} />
                        </label>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label className="masterfile-add">
                            SALES TAX
                    <input type="text"
                                name="sales_tax"
                                onChange={this.onChange}
                                value={this.state.sales_tax} />
                        </label>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label className="masterfile-add">
                            OPENING BALANCE
                    <input type="text"
                                name="opening_balance"
                                onChange={this.onChange}
                                value={this.state.opening_balance} />
                        </label>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label className="masterfile-add">
                            AREA
                    <input type="text"
                                name="area"
                                onChange={this.onChange}
                                value={this.state.area} />
                        </label>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <Link to="/masterfiledisplay">
                            <button onClick={() => this.props.updateData({
                                code: this.state.code,
                                head_of_account: this.state.head_of_account,
                                address: this.state.address,
                                telephone_no: this.state.telephone_no,
                                sales_tax: this.state.sales_tax,
                                opening_balance: this.state.opening_balance,
                                area: this.state.area,
                                masterfile_no:this.state.masterfile_no

                            })}
                                onChange={this.onChange}
                            >
                                Update
                        </button>
                        </Link>
                    </p>
                </div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    masterfile: state.masterfileReducer.masterfile
});
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    { getData, updateData }
)(UpdateMasterfile)
```

in order to update my data that is present in the database if there is another method please let me know thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass an object to history and the custom parameters can be passed as state object

```
this.props.history.push({
  pathname: "/masterfileupdate/" + masterfile.masterfile_no,
  state: { masterfile } // pass data here
});
```

In your `UpdateMasterfile` component, you can retrieve the `masterfile` data as `this.props.location.state.masterfile`

Comment: i tried using this.props.location.state but it wasnt displaying the data

Comment: What is the value of `this.props.location` if you console.log it?

Comment: it doesnt show any value when i console log this.props.location

Comment: Is your route file correct, can you add that in the code as well. I have made here a sample demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-c6zul4 . It get the state in location.

Comment: the problem solved as i had a problem with my route file itself thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can pass props to the history. for example:

```
this.props.history.push({
  path: '/users',
  search: '?userid=12',
  state: { detail: res.data }
})
```

Also you can use the below code for the Link component:

```
<Link to={{
      path: '/users',
      search: '?userid=12',
      state: { detail: res.data }
    }}>User</Link>
```

**EDIT: I have provided full example here:**

**App.js**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import FirstPage from "./parent-child/FirstPage";
import SecondPage from "./parent-child/SecondPage";
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <Link to="/first">First Page</Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <hr/>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/">
                            {/*<Home/>*/}
                        </Route>
                        <Route path="/first">
                            <FirstPage/>
                        </Route>
                        <Route path="/users">
                            <SecondPage/>
                        </Route>

                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

**FirstPage Component**

```
import {useHistory, withRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import React, {useContext, useEffect} from "react";

const FirstPage = props => {
    let history = useHistory();

    const clickHandler = event => {
        history.push({
            pathname: '/users',
            search: '?userid=12',
            state: {detail: 'This is very detail'}
        });
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={clickHandler}>Click Me</button>
        </div>
    );
};
export default withRouter(FirstPage);
```

**SecondPage Component**

```
import {useHistory, withRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import React, {useContext, useEffect} from "react";

const SecondPage = props => {
    let history = useHistory();
    let location = history.location;
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(location.pathname);
        console.log(location.search);
        console.log(location.state.detail);
    }, [location]);

    return (
        <div>
            pathname: {location.pathname}
            <br/>
            search: {location.search}
            <br/>
            state.detail: {location.state.detail}
        </div>
    );
};
export default withRouter(SecondPage);
```

Comment: it doesn't work sir i still cannot send the data to the other page

Comment: @yashb, sir I have added full example in my answer. Please check it it works perfectly.